# Realm Query in React Native Returns Realm Object Instead of Class Instance

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, realm

I have a model like this, to be able to store details field as JSON

```
class Person  {
  set details(data) { this._details = data ? JSON.stringify(data) : null; }
  get details() { return this._details ? JSON.parse(this._details) : null; }
}

Person.schema = {
  name: 'Person',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'string',
    name: 'string',
    _details: { type: 'string', optional: true }
  }
};
```

Now when I do

```
realm.write(() => {
  // this is a write block for some other objects,
  // but at some point I need to find a person
  let person = realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Person', id);
  console.log(person);
});
```

It will log out an instance of RealmObject with getters and setters for `_details` but nothing for `details`, so its not an instance of Person, am I missing something here?

I also tried `class Person extends Realm.Object { ... }` but nothing changed. I read the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/react-native/latest/#models) and assumed it should work this way, and I hope it does otherwise I'll have to change a lot of code.

**UPDATE**

Temporarily fixed (hacked) it by doing

```
let _person = realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Person', id);
if (_person) {
  let person = new Person();
  _.assign(person, _person);
}
```

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code where you initialize your Realm? You need to pass your object constructor rather than a string in the schema array in order to get your objects back. So if you are initializing your realm as

```
var realm = new Realm({schema: [Person]})
```

then in theory everything should work as you expect.

Comment: `import Person from './models/Person'; const realm = new Realm({ schema: [ Person ], schemaVersion: 1 });`